# Where the Animator Avatar was taken from (Unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, avatar, animator

I just learned to make games in Unity, I'm still confused about using [animator component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mctHl.png) animator component. I got some characters from Unity Asset, some provide avatars some do not. What should I do if there is no avatar? Can I make it myself or what? the asset is named "Tiger King"
Please give me an explanation or just send the tutorial links, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends heavily on the character. Characters are made up of a lot of different parts to firstly exist (model, UV, texture) and then secondly to animate (bones, rig, animation). If the model you have is not rigged and you are asking this question, the work put in to rig a 3D model is more than I am thinking you can do right now.

If [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/animals/tiger-king-160096) is the asset you are talking about, it is animated and looks properly rigged. All an `avatar` in Unity is, is a way to map and configure bones of a character. I would read up on the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/class-Avatar.html) about avatars.

As long as the asset you have has the same bone structure for each animation, you can create a single avatar and re-use it. Due to the animation being a tiger, you will need to use a [generic rig](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GenericAnimations.html) instead of a humanoid rig.

As the process is hard to explain through a forum, you might find one of these tutorials useful:

- [Unity Mecanim Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xx21y9eJq1U&ab_channel=Unity)
- [Unity Avatar Masks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dMoRECcstQ&ab_channel=Unity)
- [Brackey's Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Htl7ysv10Qs&ab_channel=Brackeys)

Comment: Thank you so much, I change the rig from legacy to generic and it works